# Remove Twilio Demo URL to SMS and Voice through REST API

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying to figure out how I can [update] the IncomingPhoneNumber to remove the 'Demo' Url set for Voice and Sms when a phone number is purchased.

For example my VoiceUrl is set to "https://demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice/" in the Twilio UI console. I know I can just remove it from the console but I am hoping there is a way that I can set it from a REST Service such as through the IncomingPhoneNumberResource.Update?

any resource to check into?

Comment: Word-for-word duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71623153/remove-twilio-demo-url-for-sms-and-voice-through-rest-api Is this a new account where you're posting the same question?

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. If that's the case, please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.